# How to pass Assertion Failures

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assertion

I am trying to automate a webpage using Selenium Webdriver +Java+TestNG Framework.

```
Assert.assertEquals(rs.totalarea(), "400");
Assert.assertEquals(rs.totalgallons(), "1");
```

How can I execute the second assertion statement even if the first one fails. try catch block is not working for me.

Thank you

Comment: It throws an AssertionError, which you should be able to catch. Otherwise it appears to simply do a `expected.equals(actual) && actual.equals(expected)` - so you could do that manually and store in two booleans, that you can inspect. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/Assert.java

Answer (score 2):

You can use Soft Assertion. Soft Assertions are the type of assertions that do not throw an exception when an assertion fails and would continue with the next step after asserting the statement. Have a look into [this](https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/01/13/hard-and-soft-assertions-in-selenium/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Assertions:

- Hard Assert - what you are using
- Soft Assert - what you need to use

The general assert is Hard Assert:

Hard Assert: throws an AssertException immediately when an assert statement fails and test suite continues with next test
Hard Assert marks test method as fail if assert condition gets failed and the remaining steps inside the method will be aborted.

Soft Asset: doesn't throw an exception when an assert fails and continue with the next step after the assert statement. First it collects the errors then it will throw exceptions when you use assertAll().

This is how you use soft assert:

```
SoftAssert softAssertion= new SoftAssert();

softAssertion.assertTrue(false);

softAssertion.assertAll();
```